# can I forward same animationController again after AnimationStatus.completed

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to make same animationController forward when the animation status is completed, and setState to update value which is inside animation tween, so the second animationController forward will achieve different animation, is that possible? thank you!

```
GestureDetector(
    
        onTap: () {
          if (firstController.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
            firstController.forward();
          } else if (firstController.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
            setState(() {

              double firstOpacity = 1.0;  //new value
              double secondOpacity = 0.7;//new value
              double thirdOpacity = 0.4;//new value
            });
            firstController.forward();  // now it does not work
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: firstController,
              builder: _buildAnimation,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that and more! [This api article talks about staggered animations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations) where you can set an interval percentage of the entire animation to your specific animation. The `Interval` part is where you set those values.

```dart
width = Tween<double>(
  begin: 50.0,
  end: 150.0,
).animate(
  CurvedAnimation(
    parent: controller,
    curve: Interval(
      0.125, 0.250,
      curve: Curves.ease,
    ),
  ),
);
```

About the `AnimationController`, you have some methods there to help, look [this api article about them](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) and search for `repeat`, `reset` and `reverse` methods and look the parameters that you have. You can do a lot with Flutter.

***Edit:***

If you want to make a 1/3 animation that pauses before continuing, you can do something like:

```dart
    final animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    final animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: const Interval(
          0,
          1 / 3,
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
        ),
      ),
    );
    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      animationController.stop(); // For example, but read the documentation about the stop method
    });
```

Comment: Hi Felipe thanks a lot for your comment, I have read this article and followed the instruction too, but maybe I didnt understand totally, in this article I have to go through the full animation, but what I want is to divide the full animation process into maybe three parts based on interval, so first button click, only 1/3 animation is proceeded, and break, and then second click, the 1/3 - 2/3 is proceeded and so on, now im trying to use addStatusListener, so maybe I can switch to different case, hopefully it works with the combination of animationController what do you think

Comment: Edited and added an example for you

Comment: Hi Felipe Thanks for the updating, that is inspirational, I will check documentation also!

Answer (score 2):

I hope you will get an idea from these [links](https://github.com/blackshadowsoftwareltd/Fisherman-Fishing-Animation/blob/main/lib/main.dart) and code.

```
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
        reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500))
      ..forward();
    _animationController.addListener(() {
      if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
        _animationController.reverse();
      } else if (_animationController.isDismissed) {
        _animationController.forward();
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
    _animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    _animation = Tween(begin: -.6, end: .4).animate(_animation);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Blackshadow, thanks for the help, the setState inside the addListener part I never thought about, that could work for my case:)